# How to refactor promises all chain using async await Node js and sequelize ORM

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, aws-lambda, sequelize.js

I want to refactor code for chain of promises by async, await. I have sequelize ORM for DB management and the code is written in AWS Lambda function having multiple middleware. In such cases I have to traverse code for multiple entries using sequelize transactions. It is easy to manage using promise.all() but need to change it to async await syntax for cleaner code.
Here are my demo code.

```
  /*  get all invoice where user_id === current logged in user, and where status != "paid" */
  db.Invoice.findAll({
      where: {
          user_id: currentLoggedInUser,
          status: {
              $ne: "paid"
          }
      }
  }).then(invoices => {
      if (!invoices || invoices === null) {
          return false;
      }

      function addScheduledTransactionAttempts(invoice, tryPayOnDate, t) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              /* check If any ScheduledTransactionAttempts exists for this invoice.id */
              db.ScheduledTransactionAttempts.find({
                      where: {
                          invoice_id: invoice.id
                      }
                  })
                  .then(function(attempts) {
                      if (attempts) {
                          attempts
                              .destroy({}, {
                                  transaction: t
                              })
                              .then(deletedAttempts => {
                                  console.log("Attempts Record Deleted: ", deletedAttempts);
                              })
                              .catch(error => {
                                  reject(error);
                                  t.rollback();
                              });
                      }

                      return db.ScheduledTransactionAttempts.create({
                              invoice_id: invoice.id,
                              payment_source_id: PaymentMethodId,
                              try_pay_on_date: tryPayOnDate,
                              stripe_customer_id: currentLogInStripeCustomerId
                          }, {
                              transaction: t
                          })
                          .then(function(attempt) {
                              resolve(attempt.id);
                          })
                          .catch(error => {
                              reject(error);
                              t.rollback();
                          });
                  })
                  .catch(error => {
                      reject(error);
                      t.rollback();
                  });
          });
      }
      //Run transaction to addScheduledTransactionAttempts
      return db.sequelize.transaction().then(function(t) {
          let promiseArr = [];
          var i = 0;

          invoices.forEach(function(invoice) {
              var schedulePaymentDate = moment(paymentDate);
              if (invoice) {
                  let tryPayOnDate = schedulePaymentDate
                      .add(i, "month")
                      .format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                  promiseArr.push(
                      addScheduledTransactionAttempts(invoice, tryPayOnDate, t)   //calling above function
                  );
                  i++;
              }
          });

          //now execute promise all
          Promise.all(promiseArr)
              .then(function(result) {
                  t.commit();
                  return true;
              })
              .catch(function(err) {
                  t.rollback();
                  return false;
              });
      });
  });
```

In the above code I want to change

> Promise.all(promiseArr)

which is calling

> addScheduledTransactionAttempts

function to do DB queries to simple async function await process to make it easy simpler understandable without having multiple `.then` or `.then inside then` promises.

Any help regarding would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Have trim down code.is that enough now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple. `await` is valid when invoking methods that return a Promise. All of your SDK methods already return a promise, so refactoring should be quite straight forward. Here's something to get you off ground:

```
const processInvoices = async currentLoggedInUser {
  const invoices = await db.Invoice.findAll({
    where: {
      user_id: currentLoggedInUser,
      status: {
        $ne: 'paid',
      },
    },
  });

  if (yourOwnLogicForInvoicesObject) {
    for (const invoice of invoices) {
      const potentiallyFoundInvoice = await db.ScheduledTransactionAttempts.find({
        where: {
          invoice_id: invoice.id,
        },
      });
      if (potentiallyFoundInvoice) {
        await addScheduledTransactionAttempts(potentiallyFoundInvoice)
      }
    }
  }
}

const addScheduledTransactionAttempts = async invoice => {
  console.log('Do something with your invoice', invoice)
}
```

Long story short: refactor the code inside your functions into smaller functions and make these new functions `async`, just like I did with `addScheduledTransactionAttempts` and `processInvoices`

More on [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Comment: Thanks for your response.But I need transaction commit only if all the invoice operations are being successfully done else transaction needs to be rollback. So that is the hard case for me to handle async/await instead of promise.all(passedArr) .